# Class ZipArchive not found (Where to get the pre-built zip library)

Tags: php, exception, php-ziparchive

Check these images first: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLvJ9.jpg

Where can I get the zip dll. I tried downloading its source code but it requires `php.h`.

I don't want to mess around with C right now as I have so much in PHP.

Is there anywhere, obviously a trusted source I can get this library?

Notice in my `phpinfo()` page it only says zlib. and I have **php_zip.dll** in my **ext** folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by just using a pure php library alternative found here: http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/pclzip-downloads

In case anyone ever comes across the same problem. The site has also some nice libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart your web server after modifying `php.ini`. Settings changes only then take effect.

---

The screenshot shows "zlib", which is not the same as "Zip". Also make sure that you're editing the correct `php.ini` file. CLI and Webserver PHP processes may use different ones. Enable `display_startup_errors`.

Comment: This is basic knowledge obviously.